# Concatenating strings with << is adding unexpected new lines

Tags: ruby

As part of a data cleanup effort I need to append a string to the end of each line of data.

```
export = File.new('C:\clean_file.txt' , 'w+')

File.open('C:\dirty_file.txt').each_with_index do |line, index|
    start_string = line.to_s

    # start_string => "23-SEP-13","201309","208164","F5140"
    # some gsub code on start_string...
    # start_string => "09/23/2013","201309","208164","Customer1"

    decoded_string = start_string
    decoded_string << %q(,"Accounts")
    export.puts decoded_string
end
```

However, when I attempt to append the string with the << operator, I'm getting an extra carriage return:

```
# clean_file.txt looks like this =>
line1: "09/23/2013","201309","208164","Customer1"
line2: ,"Accounts"
line3: "09/24/2013","201309","208165","Customer2"
line4: ,"Accounts"
# etc.
```

I tried:

```
decoded_string = start_string + %q("Accounts")
```

but got the same result, and it seems like << is the preferred way to concatenate strings in Ruby. How should I be appending strings to ensure 'clean_file.txt' looks like the below?

```
# clean_file.txt SHOULD love look like this =>
line1: "09/23/2013","201309","208164","Customer1","Accounts"
line2: "09/24/2013","201309","208165","Customer2","Accounts"
# etc.
```

Comment: Dan, more Ruby-like would be: `export.puts (line.chomp.gsub(...) << %q(,"Accounts"))`.

Comment: Thanks Cary -- idiomatic info like that is super helpful to a beginner like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
start_string = line.to_s
```

to

```
start_string = line.chomp
```

The newlines are coming from the lines read from the file.

Comment: Matt -- you recommendation solved my problem perfectly. Thank you so much!